# Where voltage is lost in an emitter follower?

Tags: transistors, emitter-follower, voltage, common-collector

I'd wanted to know what happens in an NPN emitter follower with \${\delta}V=Vcc-Vee\$. At which junction does voltage drop? May this drop be fatal to a transistor?

Comment: You can also put a schematic of the emitter follower using the inbuilt schematic builder/as an image.

Comment: Is it necessary? I wanted to draw it at first but it will clarify nothing in the question and only add complexity.

Comment: To clarify what are the three terms in your equation. What are the voltages you speak about.

Comment: Those are quite typical for any transistors. However, if you wish I'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a loss of one diode drop in the base-emitter junction, and the remainder of the drop is in the collector-base junction.  Yes this can cause overheating and destroy the transistor.

Comment: I suggest that most of the loss is at collector-base junction (when \$Vcc > Vb + Vbe\$), am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the total voltage drop is significantly more than a diode drop, as will typically be the case.